# Difference between initializing array in Widget's class variable and constructor?

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

Is there a difference if I initialize an array in the class variables of a widget or in it's constructor?

To be clear, what is the difference between this (Declaration 1) :

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare" //
        , "dijit/_WidgetBase" //
        , "dojox/dtl/_Templated"
        , 'dojo/domReady!'
        ], function(declare, WidgetBase, Templated){
    return declare([WidgetBase, Templated], {
            controls: [],
            constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
                this.inherited(arguments);
            }
});
```

and this (Declaration 2):

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare" //
        , "dijit/_WidgetBase" //
        , "dojox/dtl/_Templated"
        , 'dojo/domReady!'
        ], function(declare, WidgetBase, Templated){
    return declare([WidgetBase, Templated], {
            constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.controls= [];
            }
});
```

The difference in these declarations is of the attribute `controls`. In Declaration 1 it is initialized as a class member variable. In Declaration 2 it it initialized in the constructor and the class refers to it.

What I have noticed is, that if we use Declaration 1, then the `widget.controls` array is shared among different instances of the widget. To be clear, if we use Declaration 1 and do:

```
var widget1= new Widget();
var widget2= new Widget();
```

then, `widget1.controls` refers to the same array as `widget2.controls`. This is not the case with Declaration 2. And this is also not the case, if we use a combination of Declaration 1 and Declaration 2, i.e if we put `controls: null` in class member variables and initialize `this.controls= []` in the constructor. So Declaration 3 becomes:

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare" //
        , "dijit/_WidgetBase" //
        , "dojox/dtl/_Templated"
        , 'dojo/domReady!'
        ], function(declare, WidgetBase, Templated){
    return declare([WidgetBase, Templated], {
            controls: null,
            constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.controls= [];
            }
});
```

This also works as per my expectation. Any thoughts as to where I am going wrong or what is it that I am not understanding here?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that simple types are assigned by value, whereas objects are assigned by reference, in JavaScript arrays are objects (in your case `controls`).

If your class contains arrays or other objects, they should be declared in the `constructor()` so that each instance gets its own copy.

Simple types as strings, numbers, booleans, null, could be declared in the class directly because simple types are assigned by value.

Example:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "my/Foo"], function(declare, Foo){
  return declare(null, {
    arr: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // object. shared by all instances!
    num: 5,              // simple type value non-object. not shared.
    str: "string",       // simple type value non-object. not shared.
    obj: new Foo(),      // object. shared by all instances!

    constructor: function(){
      this.arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]; // per-instance object.
      this.obj = new Foo();      // per-instance object.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So this is not a DOJO issue but JS issue?

Comment: @Himanshu this is how JavaScript has been designed and not necessary an issue :)

Comment: Well explained @GibboK , :)